# Restore Azure Service Fabric backup

Tags: c#, backup, azure-service-fabric

I have been using the code from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app to create backups for our current project, but I am unable to invoke the data loss method using power shell script to trigger the restore.

Does anyone have experience with this or have another method for creating backups and restoring them?

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue you are running in to?

The documentation for specific [CmdLet is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt126016.aspx).

You will need the [Azure Powershell Cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125965.aspx).

Guidance on how to install the Azure Cmdlets [is here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/).

You will also need to login to Azure and make sure you are pointed at the right tenancy. Some code to assist with this is below. Give more details on the error you are receiving and that will help people to give a more specific answer.

```
# To login to Azure Resource Manager
Login-AzureRmAccount

# You can also use a specific Tenant if you would like a faster login experience
# Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId xxxx

# To view all subscriptions for your account
Get-AzureRmSubscription

# To select a default subscription for your current session
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName “Free Trial” | Select-AzureRmSubscription

# View your current Azure PowerShell session context
# This session state is only applicable to the current session and will not affect other sessions
Get-AzureRmContext
```